# Make the Unity top panel look like the one on the lock screen/greeter

Tags: lock-screen, panel

I like the way top bar looks on the lock screen (Ubuntu 15.04). It's dark and translucent. How can I make it look like that when logged in?

[image: greeter/lock screen with dark translucent top panel]

Answer (score 5):

You can do that. Install **Unity Tweak Tool** for more customization options.

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

Open UTT and navigate to the tab **Panel** where you can set the transparency level of the top bar.

However, the menu items will still be opaque.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Unity Tweak Tool. For those reading this... open the "Panel" tab and set "Transparency Level" as wished.

Comment: I just noticed it actually looks different. You can set transparency but you can't choose the color of the bar or remove the drop shadow. is it possible to make it look exactly like the one on the lock screen?